# What does "&" mean in '&$var' in PHP?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

What does **"&"** mean in **'&$var'**  in **PHP**? Can someone help me to explain this further. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13):

It means pass the variable by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), rather than passing the value of the variable. This means any changes to that parameter in the preparse_tags function remain when the program flow returns to the calling code.

```
function passByReference(&$test) {
    $test = "Changed!";
}

function passByValue($test) {
    $test = "a change here will not affect the original variable";
}

$test = 'Unchanged';
echo $test . PHP_EOL;

passByValue($test);
echo $test . PHP_EOL;

passByReference($test);
echo $test . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Unchanged

Unchanged

Changed!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a variable to a function by reference. This function will be able to modify the original variable.

You can define the passage by reference in the function definition with **&**

for example..

```
<?php
function changeValue(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$result=5;
changeValue($result);

echo $result; // $result is 6 here
?>
```

By default, function arguments are passed by value (so that if the value of the argument within the function is changed, it does not get changed outside of the function). To allow a function to modify its arguments, they must be passed by reference.

> To have an argument to a function always passed by reference, prepend
>   an ampersand (&) to the argument name in the function definition.